# Java List that will be remembered through each iteration

Tags: java, class, binary-search-tree

I have created a BST in a class called BinaryTree

I am trying to create nodes with specific values in class called Test and add them to binary tree in class called AddToTree. At the moment I have created a class called BinaryTree which knows how to create a BST when its given the correct values. 
It is working fine when i create multiple nodes inside class AddToTree but when I try to do it from class Test I believe the tree starts from a scratch with every new node. My question is how can I make it remember the all values that have been added previously.

Here is the method (addToBST) that Test class calls out which should add nodes to the tree and remember them :

```
public class AddToTree implements SomeClass {
     private BinaryTree waitingLine1 = new BinaryTree();
     private BinaryTree waitingLine2 = new BinaryTree();

     @Override
     public SimpleEntry<SomeClass, Someclass> addToBST(Someclass someclass) throws IllegalArgumentException {

            waitingLine1.addNode(fristData, secondData, thirdData);
            return null;
        }
```

Now i call it with my Test class:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo();
    }

    static void foo() {
        AddToTree impl = new AddToTree();
        addNodeAndTest(30, 120, null);
   }

   private static void addNodeAndTest(AddToTree impl, int firstValue, int secondValue, int thirdValue) {
     //Some code
 }
```

I believe that adding the BST class is irrelevant since i dont create a list in that class. Should I create a new class with the list implementation or how should I make it remember the list.
I would be really thankful if you could point me in the right direction.
If needed I can provide additional information.

EDIT!
Here is how i create the BinaryTree (addNode method).

```
public class BinaryTree{

Node root = null;

public void addNode(int firstValue, int secondValue, int thirdValue) {

    Node newNode = new Node(fristValue, secondValue, thirdValue);
    if (root == null) {
        root = newNode;
    } else {
        Node focusNode = root;
        Node parent;
        while (true) {
            parent = focusNode;
            if (ID < focusNode.firstValue) {
                focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
                if (focusNode == null) {
                    parent.leftChild = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
                if (focusNode == null) {
                    parent.rightChild = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. Could you provide a [mcve] or at least some example of what you'd want to do? And since you're referencing `addNode(...)` we'd need to at least see the relevant parts of that method.

Comment: I tried explaining it better.. is it understandable enough at the moment?

Comment: Well, one problem I have is with "remember the list" - Which list? Where should it be available? And "I believe the tree starts from a scratch with every new node" - what's the problem here (assuming you realize that each instance of `AddToTree` creates a new tree instance which probably isn't what you want - but that design is strange anyways)?

Comment: That kinda was the question.. the part where you assumed that i realize since I do but how can I work around it

Comment: Normally you'd either have an `add(...)` method on the tree itself or alternatively pass the tree _and_ the value to some utility method, e.g. `add( tree, value )`;